# How to get value in the session in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-session

I'm a beginner in jQuery.
I want to set the values in an HTML page and I have to get them in another HTML page.

Here is the piece of code I am trying now:

To set the value in session:

```
$.session.set(userName, $("#uname").val());
```

To get the value from session:

```
$.session.get('userName');
```

Comment: Is `$.session` a plugin?

Comment: `$.session` is either a plugin or you're confusing server-side and client-side coding

Comment: Are you using an additional plugin for session?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123622/how-to-set-session-variable-in-jquery

Comment: yes..i have attached a session plugin

Comment: In the first line, you set `userName` which seems to be a variable. Then in your get function, you attempt to get access to an object with a string that is not a variable. unless `var userName = userName`, then this scenario will never work. what does the first `userName` hold?

Comment: This is probably the plugin https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin ? Right?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - I'd suggest you type that up as an answer.  It's a good catch, and I'm pretty sure it's what the OP's problem is.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Did you mean `var userName = "userName"`?

Comment: @Asad yea exactly, oopsies

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you are using [this plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin), you are misusing the `.set` method. `.set` must be passed the name of the key as a string as well as the value. I suppose you meant to write:

```
$.session.set("userName", $("#uname").val());
```

This sets the `userName` key in session storage to the value of the input, and allows you to retrieve it using:

```
$.session.get('userName');
```

Answer (score 3):

Sessions are stored on the server and are set from server side code, not client side code such as JavaScript.

What you want is a cookie, someone's given a brilliant explanation in this Stack Overflow question here:
[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

You could potentially use sessions and set/retrieve them with jQuery and AJAX, but it's complete overkill if Cookies will do the trick.