# Is it only by submitting the form that the session captcha can be get?

Tags: php, jquery, session, captcha

I want to get the session captcha value in the onsubmit event of the form , so if the text entered is different of the session captcha data then I will cancel form submission. The problem is that I cannot get the session captcha value on document ready :

file of the captcha generation is named securitecode.php :

```
<?php
session_start();

$largeur  = 120;
$hauteur  = 40;
$longueur = 5;
$liste = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$code    = '';
$counter = 0;

$image = @imagecreate($largeur, $hauteur) or die('Impossible d\'initializer GD')
;

for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ ) {
   imageline($image,
   mt_rand(0,$largeur), mt_rand(0,$hauteur),
   mt_rand(0,$largeur), mt_rand(0,$hauteur),
   imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(200,255),mt_rand(200,255),mt_rand(200,255)
));
 }

for( $i=0, $x=0; $i<$longueur; $i++ ) {
   $charactere = substr($liste, rand(0, strlen($liste)-1), 1);
   $x += 10 + mt_rand(0,10);
   imagechar($image, mt_rand(3,5), $x, mt_rand(5,20), $charactere,
   imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155)));
   $code .= $charactere;
 }

  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($image);
  imagedestroy($image);

  $_SESSION['securecode'] = $code;
?>
```

In my web page I create the image captcha :

```
...
<img id="captcha_img" src="securitecode.php" />
<input type="text" id="captcha" />
<span id="msg_captcha"></span>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#msg_captcha').html("<?php echo $_SESSION['securecode']; ?>");
});
</script>
```

When the page loads for the first time there is nothing displayed inside the #msg_captcha span ! So how to get the captcha session data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is because of the way sessions work.**

Session values is available when a session is over and the session data has been written to the session file.

When requesting the page, you actually try to obtain a session value that hasn't yet been set for two reasons.

1. The captcha image is loaded AFTER your initial request, but PHP has already handled the `<?php echo $_SESSION['securecode']; ?>` part.
2. The `$_SESSION['securecode']` value is written after the image has been loaded.

So basically, your solution is trying to read values too early.

**The solution?**

Check the captcha code with AJAX or verify the captcha code on the next request.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't run PHP that way.
PHP is a server side language, javascript is client side.
Maybe [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510590/how-to-get-value-in-the-session-in-jquery) can help you.

Comment: You can read php variables with JSON as long as the session value exist before the JS is run

Comment: Yes you can, but JS can't run a PHP script in the way it's described in the question