# Set session variable from jQuery

Tags: jquery, session

When my page is loaded, it displays some TweenLite animation, using jQuery. Javascript code for animation is located in separate .js file.

I need to keep the animation when the page is opened for the first time, and remove it afterwards. The obvious way for me would be to use a session variable which should be set after animation is complete.

I know that jQuery can access session variables through ajax, but I cannot find any examples of doing it.

I found similar question here, on stackoverflow, and the only answer to it is to use a localStorage. How is it different from a session?

Comment: Couldnt you just access the session variable with javascript?

Comment: Session = cookie behind the scenes... why not just use a cookie?

Comment: You can see the solution in this [answered question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123622/how-to-set-session-variable-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this without jquery:

```
var totalVisits = "<%HttpContext.Current.Session("TOTALVISITS")%>";
```

Comment: I use PHP on the page. I understand the idea of counting visits though, and I like it. Thank you.

Comment: May be you can try this for PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365738/how-to-access-php-session-variables-from-jquery-function-in-a-js-file

Comment: As I said, the javascript code is in .js file, not .php. The only reason I did not accept your answer yet is because I have to wait a couple more minutes. :)