# Load splash screen only once at start in php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, splash-screen

I have already created a splash screen using jquery's fadeOut option. It is working fine but the problem is the screen is loading every time I click to go to next page. 
I need splash screen only at startup.
I think I need to use session or something but I am not able to find the solution. 
I am using following script.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#splashscreen").click(function () {
    $("#splashscreen").fadeOut(2000); 
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if( $.cookie('splashscreen') == null ) { // Here you are checking if cookie is existing if not you are showing a splash screen and set a cookie
        $("#splashscreen").fadeIn();
        $.cookie("splashscreen", 1, { expires : 10 }); // cookie is valid for 10 days
    }
    $("#splashscreen").click(function () {
        $("#splashscreen").fadeOut(2000); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added css display none property at else part and seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookie and check for it when page refreshes. I suggest you to use library like this:

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Answer (score 0):

One option is to handle this in PHP, but you also can use the local storage in JS.
Here is a related Topic: [How to set session variable in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123622/how-to-set-session-variable-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a session for this. on the first line of your code add `<?php session_start();`

Now, later in your code, you can do:

```
if(!$_SESSION['splash'])
{
    $_SESSION['splash'] = true;

    //echo your splash code here
}
```