# Add to cart using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mode

I'm trying to model with add to cart using jQuery. but it has a small issue of how can I solve that. if I click the `mybtn` button model shows and work properly but quantity it's not working properly. How can I solve that? Thanks in advance.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.2/jquery.modal.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.2/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="shoe single-item hvr-outline-out">
    <form method="post" action="#" class="cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" id="<%= doc._id%>">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" id="pname_<%= doc._id%>" name="shoe_item" value="<%=doc.product_name%>">
      <input type="hidden" id="amount_<%= doc._id%>" name="amount" value="<%=doc.price%>">
    </form>
    <button type="submit" id="myBtn1_<%= doc._id%>" data-id="<%= doc._id%>" value="<%= doc._id%>" class="shoe-cart pshoe-cart myBtn"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> <br/>
        <center>
          <table class="row"> </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myBtn").click(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var count = 0;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myBtn").click(function() {
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      var p_name = $('.cart').find('#pname_' + id).val();
      var count1 = count++;
      var amount = $('.cart').find('#amount_' + id).val();
      var html = "<tr id='tr_'" + id + "><td>" + p_name + "</td><td>" + amount + "</td><td><input type='text' name='count' id='count_" + id + "' size='3' value='" + count + "'></td>/tr>";
      var quan = $('.row').find('#count_' + id).val();
      if (!quan) {
        $('.row').append(html);
      } else {
        $('#count_' + id).append(count);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: can you show your modal code ?

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <br/>
            <center>
             <table class="row">
              
             </table>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: this is my model code

Comment: from where are you getting `quan` ? your  `<form>` doesn't have quantity input?  I didn't get this `$('.row').find('#count_'+id).val()` .Also, post code in your question not in comments

Comment: Added modal to markup above and linked libraries...

Comment: in html variable i append this count id and then get this quan

Answer (score 0):

Add click event after modal show

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $(".myBtn").click(function() {
     //your code here
  });
})
```

Comment: thank you, but how to add to cart properly in my code

Comment: Use local storage to store user selected data, then in checkout page process the data to server. To display the data, get the data from local storage... Don't forget to clear the local storage after processing
check this anwer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123622/how-to-set-session-variable-in-jquery