# Dynamic fields added to form disappears on page reload

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my javascript code

```js
<script>

var i = 0; /* Set Global Variable i */
function increment(){
i += 1; /* Function for automatic increment of field's "Name" attribute. */
}
   
function removeElement(parentDiv, childDiv){
if (childDiv == parentDiv){
alert("The parent div cannot be removed.");
}
else if (document.getElementById(childDiv)){
var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
parent.removeChild(child);
}
else{
alert("Child div has already been removed or does not exist.");
return false;
}
}
/*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the Name text field.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function nameFunction(){
var r = document.createElement('span');
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "text");
y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Name");
var g = document.createElement("IMG");
g.setAttribute("src", "delete.png");
increment();
y.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
r.appendChild(y);
g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
r.appendChild(g);
r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
}
/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the E-mail text field.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function emailFunction(){
var r = document.createElement('span');
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "text");
y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Email");
var g = document.createElement("IMG");
g.setAttribute("src", "delete.png");
increment();
y.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
r.appendChild(y);
g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
r.appendChild(g);
r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
}
/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the Contact text field.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function contactFunction(){
var r = document.createElement('span');
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "text");
y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Contact");
var g = document.createElement("IMG");
g.setAttribute("src", "delete.png");
increment();
y.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
r.appendChild(y);
g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
r.appendChild(g);
r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
}
/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the Message textarea field.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function textareaFunction(){
var r = document.createElement('span');
var y = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
var g = document.createElement("IMG");
y.setAttribute("cols", "17");
y.setAttribute("placeholder", "message..");
g.setAttribute("src", "delete.png");
increment();
y.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
r.appendChild(y);
g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
r.appendChild(g);
r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
}
/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the Reset Button.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function AddQuestionFunction(){
var r = document.createElement('span');
var y = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
y.setAttribute("cols", "15");
y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Question");
var g = document.createElement("IMG");
g.setAttribute("src", "delete.png");
increment();
y.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
r.appendChild(y);
g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
r.appendChild(g);
r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
}

function OptionFunction(){
var r = document.createElement('span');
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "radio");
y.setAttribute("value", "rad");
y.setAttribute("name", "radio");
var z = document.createElement("INPUT");
z.setAttribute("type", "text");
//y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Contact");
var g = document.createElement("IMG");
g.setAttribute("src", "delete.png");
increment();
y.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
r.appendChild(y);
z.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
r.appendChild(z);
g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
r.appendChild(g);
r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
}

function TextFunction(){
var r = document.createElement('span');
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "text");
y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Text");
var g = document.createElement("IMG");
g.setAttribute("src", "delete.png");
increment();
y.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
r.appendChild(y);
g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
r.appendChild(g);
r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
}

function CheckBoxFunction(){
var r = document.createElement('span');
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
var z = document.createElement("INPUT");
z.setAttribute("type", "text");
//y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Contact");
var g = document.createElement("IMG");
g.setAttribute("src", "delete.png");
increment();
y.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
r.appendChild(y);
z.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
r.appendChild(z);
g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
r.appendChild(g);
r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
}

function resetElements(){
document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = '';
}

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Create Dynamic form Using JavaScript</title>
<script src="js/form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main_content">
<!--
========================================================================================
Header Div.
========================================================================================
-->
<div class="first">
</div>
<!--
======================================================================================
This Div is for the Buttons. When user click on buttons, respective field will appear.
=======================================================================================
-->
<div class="two">
<h4>Frequently Used Form Fields</h4>
<button id="name" onclick="nameFunction()">Name</button>
<button onclick="emailFunction()">Email</button>
<button onclick="contactFunction()">Contact</button>
<button onclick="textareaFunction()">Message</button>   
<button onclick="AddQuestionFunction()">AddQuestion</button>

<select id="QuestionType" name="Question Type">
    <center>
        <option id="btAdd" value="Add Text Element" class="bt" selected="" onclick="TextFunction()" >Add Text</option>
        <option id="btRadio" value="rad" onclick="OptionFunction()" >Radio</option>
        <option id="btCheck" value="Checkbox" onclick="CheckBoxFunction()">Checkbox</option>
    </center>
</select>

<button onclick="resetElements()">Reset</button>
</div>
<!--
========================================================================================
This Div is meant to display final form.
========================================================================================
-->
<div class="three">
<h2>Contact Information!</h2>
<form action="#" id="mainform" method="get" name="mainform">
<span id="myForm"></span>
<p></p><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<!--
========================================================================================
Footer Div.
========================================================================================
-->
<div class="four">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a html form in which have an option of adding dynamic fields now the problem that I am facing is whenever I reload the page the dynamic fields that I have added gets disappeared..So how can I have get the dynamic fields saved in the form even after page reload?

Comment: show the code please.

Comment: If you want to restore it, you'll have to do it manually. For example, you could put it in local storage and take it out. Can you show me your code?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to save the data for the fields you have added somewhere you can use after a page reload like the local storage [How to set session variable in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123622/how-to-set-session-variable-in-jquery)

so that when you load the page you first check if fields are set in the local storage, if so render those fields